# Print the unique words in sorted form from a comma separated sequence of words

Tags: python, string, list, join, split

```
items = input("Input comma separated sequence of words")
words = [word for word in items.split(",")]
print(",".join(sorted(list(set(words)))))
```

is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your current approach looks fine to me.

Comment: Sorry but is your code not working or are you just looking for best practice/feedback? If the latter then you will want to ask on [codereview.se] as this question is Off-topic here

Comment: Which part are you trying to avoid? You’re using the python builtins which should be the fastest way to do it. Except, as pointed out below - you don’t need the list comprehension there.

Answer (score 4):

```
items = input("Input comma separated sequence of words") # dog,cat,dog,bird
words = sorted(set(items.split(',')))
print (words) #
```